# difficulty in returning string from dll function call using Win32::API import in Perl

Tags: windows, perl, winapi

The function is like this, `string MyFuntion(long,long*)`
so I have tried with lots of things but failed to get the string return.
Please help me out.

```
Win32::API->Import('My.dll','DWORD MyFunction(long a,long* b)')or die $^E;  
my $var = MyFunction(1,0);  
printf "%d : '%s'\n", length($var),$var;
```

Comment: `string` is not a C type.  What does MyFunction actually return?

Answer (score 1):

`DWORD` is just a "`long`" type, and `Win32::API` will not do any conversion on such a return value. If your function returns a `char *`, just declare its prototype as `char* MyFunction(...)`.

Or use one of the many many aliases for pointer to char that are already defined in [`Win32::API::Type`](http://cpansearch.perl.org/src/COSIMO/Win32-API-0.59/Type.pm).

---

**Edit:** It really is as simple as setting a prototype that returns `char *`. The complicated part is creating a DLL that exports the functions that you (and `Win32::API`) expects it to. This code, for example, which creates its own DLL and then imports and invokes its function through Win32::API, works on my system (Strawberry Perl 5.12.0):

```
$STRAWBERRY = "C:/strawberry512";  # YMMV

unlink "my_func.dll";

open DLL_SRC, '>', 'my_func.c';
print DLL_SRC q!
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <windows.h>

char* WINAPI MyFunc(int a, int b)
{
    char *s = (char *) malloc(32);
    if (a==0 && b==0) {
        strcpy(s, "JAPH");
    } else {
        s[0] = 32 + (a % 64);
        s[1] = 32 + (b % 64);
        s[2] = '\0';
    }
    return(s);
}
!;
close DLL_SRC;

open DLL_DEF, '>', 'my_func.def';
print DLL_DEF "EXPORTS\nMyFunc\@8\n";
close DLL_DEF;

system("$STRAWBERRY/c/bin/gcc.exe", "-c", "my_func.c") ||
system("$STRAWBERRY/c/bin/gcc.exe", 
       "-mdll",
       "-o", "junk.tmp",
       "-Wl,--base-file,my_func.tmp", "my_func.o") ||
system("$STRAWBERRY/c/bin/dlltool",
       "--dllname", "my_func.dll",
       "--base-file", "my_func.tmp",
       "--output-exp", "my_func.exp",
       "--def", "my_func.def", "-k") ||
system("$STRAWBERRY/c/bin/gcc",
       "-mdll",
       "-o", "my_func.dll",
       "my_func.o",
       "-Wl,my_func.exp") ||
print "my_func.dll seems to have created successfully.\n\n";

use Win32::API;
Win32::API->Import('my_func', 
                   'char* MyFunc(int a, int b)') or die $!,$^E;
$val = MyFunc(0,0);
print $val;
print MyFunc(1,65);
unlink "my_func.dll", "libmy_func.a", "my_func.def",
   "my_func.o", "my_func.exp", "my_func.tmp", "my_func.c";
```

If you are having trouble replicating this example, start with something simple -- a trivial function that takes no args and returns an integer, for example -- and get that working first. Check `$!` and `$^E` at every step.